# How would I select an input from a form and store it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, if i had a form like this:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="item">
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem"></button>
```

How would I output the input from the form?

Comment: What do you want to achieve from output?

Comment: *How would I out put the input form the form* bit more clear?

Comment: you can use javascript for that -> `var input = document.getElementByName('item');`

Comment: I want to output the value of the input with the name "item"

Comment: I tried using document.getElementNyName('item').value and it returned as undefined

Comment: are you sure an event was fired on clicking the button?

Comment: @Joseph718 You need to add some input in the `textbox` no input value is `undefined`

Comment: when do you want that to happen, do you want the value of the input to be stored after clicking that button?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function in which you can use `querySelector()` to get the element to get the value of the input:

```js
function outputItem(){
  var v = document.querySelector('#form1 > input[name=item]').value;
  console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="item">
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem()">ShowMe</button>
<span id="response"></span>

<script>
    function outputItem() {
        var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = item;
    }
</script>
```

Try above one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
function selectInputForm(){
const selectForm = document.querySelector('#inputForm');
}
```

Remember to add the id to the input form you want to select:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="item" id= 'inputForm' >
</form>
<button onclick="selectInputForm()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking on the button *Try it* you have write some text into the input. Otherwise, it can get an error - **undefined**.

```js
function outputItem() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("item")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="item">
</form>

<button onclick="outputItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```